# C# DataBinded ListBoxes - Sorting Issue

Tags: winforms, data-binding, sorting, listbox

I have these **ListBox** es.. all of them are **DataBind** ed to same table and they are in a table type of manner, every row corresponds to its actual value in the datbase. When i switch selection(SelectedIndexChange) on any of these ListBoxes i **change** the **SelectedIndex** of all the other **ListBox** es.

[alt text http://www.deviantart.com/download/152153617/A_piece_from_my_softs____by_junaid_saeed.png](http://www.deviantart.com/download/152153617/A_piece_from_my_softs____by_junaid_saeed.png)

Now i cannot simply select **"Sort = true"** for any of the ListBox because doing so the values in **ListBox** es will not correspond to their actual values in other **ListBox** es. I want to provide an option to sort Acoording to one of the **ListBox** while keeping the **correspondences** valid.  **HOW TO DO IT** .Any Suggestions.

I don't want to run any **Sorting Algorithm** on **ListBox**, picking every entry(**Item**) and sorting it and then changing the rest of **ListBox** es accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use a `ListView` instead of using all those list boxes. It would make your life a lot less complicated, as it supports the functionality you are requesting without you having to worry about keeping things in sync.

Comment: Yah that wud have been easy but ListBox happens to "Documented Specification" for this. I might leave Sorting but i cannot leeave ListBox :)

Comment: And you are not in a position to question the specification, even though it makes little to no sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you're needing to do exactly what you have listed, I'd recommend adding in a 'layer' of logic before actually binding to the listboxes.

i.e.:

Instead of databinding directly to the ListBoxes, create a List<> of the datarows  (or your own custom object).  When you need to sort the list, call the .Sort() method on the List<> for whatever property/column you need, and then clear out the ListBoxes, repopulate them based upon your List<> (probably adding the ListItems one at a time for each box), and then correct the SelectedIndex(es) of the ListBoxes.

By doing it this way, you never lose association between rows of the ListBoxes.